# Is it possible to render Bezier curves without polyline approximations? If so, how?

Tags: c++, directx, curve, bezier, direct2d

I'm attempting to render a parametric Bezier curve in Direct 2D with**out** any third-party libraries. Is it possible to do this without making a polyline approximation, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it is possible without using any libraries. You can always re-implement the functionalities of the libraries yourself. The question is, why bother?

Comment: It's... kind of trivial even? Just compute the coordinates on the curve (the functions are pretty basic maths), and then draw a line connecting those points. Read over the first few sections of https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo for more detailed info on that.

Comment: (note that because you're dealing with computers, every curve is technically a polyline. It just looks like a curve if the fidelity is high enough so that each sampled point maps to an adjacent pixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must, you can try to analytically rasterise curves (this includes polynomial curves such as bezier or even algebraic curves).

Here are some pointers.
http://www.josiahmanson.com/research/wavelet_rasterization/wavelet_rasterization.pdf
http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/scanline.pdf